# Prove that $\frac a{a+2b}+\frac bc+\frac{c^2}{\left(c+2a\right)^2 }\ge1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> (sqing) Let $a$, $b$, $c>0$. Prove that $\dfrac a{a+2b}+\dfrac bc+\dfrac{c^2}{\left(c+2a\right)^2 }\ge1$. [Source (unsolved)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3016623_fracaa2bfracbc__fracc2leftc2aright2_ge_1)

In this inequality, $b$ appears the least frequent, so I want to deal with it. I took $a$, $c$ as parameters and derived $b$, we have
\[\frac{\text d}{\text db}~\left(\dfrac a{a+2b}+\dfrac bc\right)=\frac1c-\frac{2a}{(a+2b)^2}.\tag1\label1\]
When $2c>a$, $\eqref1=0$ gives $b=\dfrac{\sqrt{2ac}-a}2$. When $2c\le a$, $\eqref1>0$ is true for all $b$, so $b\to0$ shall minimize the left side.

But plugging back makes the expressions complicated. What should I do?

Comment: I mean for the first case. The second case is simple.

Comment: Did you try to simplify it with $x=b/a$, $y=c/b$, and $z=a/c$, subject to $xyz=1$?

Comment: Not yet. That would be making use of the homogeneous expression. So a similar way is to directly let a variable $=1$. @Momo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{a}{a + 2b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c^2}{(c + 2a)^2} - 1\\
 \ge{}& \frac{(a + b)^2}{a(a + 2b) + bc} + \frac{c^2}{(c + 2a)^2} - 1  \\
 ={}& \frac{(2ab - ac + bc)^2}{(a^2 + 2ab + bc)(c + 2a)^2}\\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
with equality if $a:b:c = 2:1:4$.

We are done.

Comment: Can we quickly find(guess) the equality case by some method?

Comment: @youthdoo sqing's problems often have nice proofs (often C-S, AM-GM), as can be seen in AoPS. In this spirit, letting $b = 1$, then try some $a, c$.